# Вывод елементов от меньшего к большему C#

Tags: c#, .net

A, B, C и D – целые коэффициенты кубического уравнения.
Нужно вывести через пробел в порядке возрастания все корни заданного кубического уравнения.
Решил делать методом перебора чисел, все хорошо, но вот вывести в правильном порядке не выходит...

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("input.txt");
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.txt");

    string[] num = sr.ReadLine().Split();
    long a = Convert.ToInt16(num[0]);
    long b = Convert.ToInt16(num[1]);
    long c = Convert.ToInt16(num[2]);
    long d = Convert.ToInt16(num[3]);
    int x;

    for(x=-100;x<=100;x++)
    {
        if (((Math.Pow(x,3))*a + (Math.Pow(x,2))*b+c*x+d)==0)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Ну раз находить корни вы уже умеете, вам осталось найденные корни куда то сохранить (например, в список), потом отсортировать и вывести на экран.

Comment: Я пытался сделать вывод через строку и у меня это не вышло.
Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: @tym32167 `(...)==0` - ох, не умеет (

Comment: А можно спросить, что это за извращение такое - в 64-битную переменную записывать 16-битное число? Почему бы не сделать типы одинаковыми?)

Comment: @aa_talanin числа не большие и по этому я им здал тип long

Comment: Тип long(Int64) используется как раз для больших чисел. Типу Int16 соответствует ключевое слово short.

Comment: @aa_talanin  благодарен , я это не заметил

Comment: @Igor да, что то я по диагонали вопрос прочитал

Answer (score 0):

Ничего упорядочивать не надо, они и так идут по-порядку.

```
int x = -101;
double previous = Math.Pow(x, 3) * a + Math.Pow(x, 2) * b + c * x + d;
double current;
int rootIndex = 0;
for(x = -100; x <= 100; x++)
{
  current = Math.Pow(x, 3) * a + Math.Pow(x, 2) * b + c * x + d; 
  if (current * previous <= 0 && current != 0)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Root # {0} = {1}", ++rootIndex, x - 0.5));
  }
  previous = current;
}
```